# Removing inline style attributes from GWT elements

Tags: gwt, styling

I've inherited a lot of legacy GWT code that can be succinctly described as "a web developer's worst nightmare." The developers have made use of a lot of elements that have inline styles -- for example, the GWT DeckPanel.

I want to remove these inline styles so I can apply an external stylesheet, but I can't seem to find any way of doing this. I know that an inline style can be set via this: `DOM.setStyleAttribute(container1, "height", "100%");` or similar, but there doesn't seem to be any sort of corresponding `removeStyleAttribute`. There is a `DOM.removeElementAttribute` but this does not work for styles.

**Is there a way to explicitly remove all inline styling from an attribute?** I tried Googling but all I ended up finding were things related to UIBinder and lots of defensive posts from GWT devs a la "why would you want to do that?" And I can't do too much code modification since this app is massive and I'm on a deadline. We're not using UIBinder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set inline CSS styles like this:

```
Style style = widget.getElement().getStyle();
style.setPosition(Position.ABSOLUTE);
style.setTop(50, Unit.PX);
style.setLeft(0, Unit.PX);
// etc.
```

To remove styles:

```
style.clearPosition();
style.clearTop();
style.clearLeft();
```

Alternatively:

```
DOM.setStyleAttribute(element, "height", "");
```

To remove *all* inline styles for an element:

```
DOM.setElementProperty(element, "style", "");
```

You can also override inline styles with external styles by appending `!important` to the style definition. E.g.

```
.my-gwt-widget {
    height: 150px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clear the style of an element you can use the following code:

```
DOM.setElementProperty(element, "style", "");
```

Comment: deprecated as of now.